# Использование Recyrlerview для статичного списка элементов

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

[image: Скрин UI статичного списка]

Нужно отрисовать статичный список со скроллом (пример на скриншоте выше), что лучше использовать для этого - ConstraintLayout вложенным во ScrollView или RecyrlerView с локальным списком элементов? Сделал это с помощью RecyrlerView с локальным списком элементов, но терзают сомнения, насколько это правильно и хорошо для оптимизации используемой памяти приложения.

Comment: recyclerview будет удобнее, что в вашем понятии  статичный означает?

Comment: там известно, количество элементов списка заранее

Comment: так можно в recyclerview все отобразить беспроблемно) используйте этот виджет и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо)